# How does the server and client user login blend in together?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, authentication, express, mean.io

I set up a mean stack based on http://mean.io

I managed to get it running but I'm confused with the user authentication flow.

The main thing that is confusing me is the distinction between server/views and public/views.

I understand that when I want to require user auth I can do `app.get` with `auth.requiresLogin`.

But how does this mix in with the angular client side of things? How do I make the angular views available only when logged in.

My objective is to have the following:

When users go to `/` I want them to see a basic message if they are not logged in.

When they do log in, in `/` I want them to see my angular app.

I'm confused as to how to achieve that.

How do I structure my app for this purpose? Can I check in the template whether a user is logged in?

Comment: Please let me know if this is not concrete enough, I'll expand further. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You use `routeProvider`:

```
.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider',

    function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

        var access = routingConfig.accessLevels;

        $routeProvider.when('/',
        {
            templateUrl:    'partials/...',
            controller:     yourController,
            access:         access.user
        });

        $routeProvider.when('/',
        {
            templateUrl:    'partials/...',
            access:         access.anon
        });

    }]);
```

This example has to work.

Comment: One question, should my views that require auth still be in public/views?

Comment: Michael, sorry to ask so many questions but I'm really new to this, right now I have this: https://gist.github.com/trufa/5c63750b4ba22689e3ed how does this mix in with the stateProvider?